# React infinity state on console.log() using hooks why is that?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

// Im getting an infinty console.log() on the console. any help why is that

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

const App = ()=>{

    let [state, setState] = useState([])

    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(data => setState(data))


    console.log(state)

    return(
        <h1>Hey there</h1>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You call `fetch` on every render which triggers `setState` which triggers the next render. That's why you have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

`fetch` is called with every render (as well as `setState` function), which will cause an infinite loop. Move it to `useEffect` so it will be fired once, when component mounts.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
   fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
     .then(result => result.json())
     .then(data => setState(data))
}, []);
```